# How to send HTML Checkbox information and file input to java servlet within a single POST?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, servlets

I'm currently trying to build a website where the user can visualize different machine learning algorithms for a school project. However, when trying to collect the checked checkboxes and input file, I am unable to get the file within my servlet. I have checked several posts about ajax, FormData among others but none have solved the issue for me yet.

Starting at the very beginning is my HTML form containing all the required input/options for the user.

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="#" id="UploadForm">
<input id="ZeroRCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="ZeroR"><label for="ZeroRCheckBox">ZeroR</label>
<input id="OneRCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="OneR"><label for="OneRCheckBox">OneR</label>
<input id="J48CheckBox" type="checkbox" value="J48"><label for="J48CheckBox">J48</label>
<input id="RandomForrestCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="RandomForrest"><label for="RandomForrestCheckBox">RandomForrest</label>
<input id="RandomTreeCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="RandomTree"><label for="RandomTreeCheckBox">RandomTree</label>
<input id="NaiveBayesCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="NaiveBayes"><label for="NaiveBayesCheckBox">Naive Bayes</label>
<input id="NearestNeighborCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="NearestNeighbor"><label for="NearestNeighborCheckBox">Nearest Neighbor</label>
<input id="SMOCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="SMO"><label for="SMOCheckBox">SMO</label>
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv,.arff">
<p>Upload the information here!</p>
<button id="btn">Upload file!</button>
<p class="help-text" id="passwordHelpText">The input should either be in .csv or .arff format.</p>
```

This form contains the button (btn) which should trigger a JavaScript function that collects the checked boxes and the file within in FormData object. This object is then sent to the java backend using ajax.

**JavaScript**

```
function submit() {
    let algorithms = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).toArray();
    var form = $('UploadForm')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    data.append("algorithms[]", algorithms)
    $.ajax({
        url: "boundary-visualizer",
        data: {
            data: data,
        },
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", submit);
```

This information is then collected within the java servlet as follows:

**Java Servlet**

```
@MultipartConfig

...

System.out.println("GOING TO FETCH ALGORITHMS");
String[] algorithms = request.getParameterValues("algorithms[]");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(algorithms));
System.out.println("PRINTED ALGORITHMS");

System.out.println("GOING TO FETCH FILENAME");
Part filePart = request.getPart("form");String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();

System.out.println(fileName);
System.out.println("PRINTED FILENAME");
```

When checking the console to review the different print statements it shows that the algorithm array is successfully collected and printed, the file however does not show up, the and following print statements are also not executed.

**Console**

```
GOING TO FETCH ALGORITHMS
[NaiveBayes, NearestNeighbor]
PRINTED ALGORITHMS
GOING TO FETCH FILENAME
...

Followed by this error in another log

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [VisualizerServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8] with root cause
```

What could be the issue here? Or if there is an easier/better way to do this, what should I do? Any help or suggestions are welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: @BalusC Right I missed that one indeed, I tried calling it form because maybe it worked, but I changed it back to 'file'  which gave me the following error

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [VisualizerServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8] with root cause

Which probably means that my file is in a data storage?

Comment: Hi you missed `#` i.e : `$('#UploadForm')..`

Comment: Ooh right! added it